# missing or unknown entry.level error using python selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

```
chromedriver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Python3\chromedriver.exe')
#os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
chrome_options = Options()

# this is the preference we're passing
prefs = {"download.default_directory" : "F:/"}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
#driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
chromedriver.get("{some website which has the element with ID xxxx_TxtSearch}")
num = chromedriver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id, 'TxtSearch')]")
```

The last line is producing the error below. Attaching screenshot for reference. I am sure this was not causing any problems until yesterday and chromedriver is present at the given location.

[image: Stacktrace of the error]

Comment: Any specific reason for the downvote ?

Comment: Did you solve this? How? Thank you.

Comment: Yes I did, this seems to be a problem with the chromedriver. I updated the chromedrive from their website and it resolved this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue with chromedriver 2.25

Upgrade to 2.35 and issue is solved.